# Excel | Priority-Queue/Combining ISNA() and Cell=0 in OR-Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, priority-queue

I created this nested Excel formula to display the first available value (<>0) in line with my prioritisation (see below) of sources. The first value that is available and <>0 shall be returned to cell Y6.

*Prio:*
 1. Z6
 2. AA6
 3. AB6
 4. AC6

*Formula:*
=IFS(AND(ISNA(Z6)=FALSE;Z6<>0);Z6;AND(OR(ISNA(Z6);Z6=0);AND(ISNA(AA6)=FALSE;AA6<>0));AA6;AND(OR(ISNA(Z6);Z6=0);OR(ISNA(AA6);AA6=0));AB6)

As you can see AC6 is currently not included, as an error occurred before I got to this part. It seems that

**OR(ISNA(Z6);Z6=0)**

does lead to an #N/A-error.

Hence, my question, how can I combine **ISNA(Z6)** and **Z6=0** within an OR-Function? 
In general, if someone has a more elegant solution instead of my approach with the IFS-Function highly appreciated too. :)

Regarding the possible values in the respective cells:

1. Z6  OR(#N/A;0;value<>0)
2. AA6 OR(#N/A;0;value<>0)
3. AB6 OR(Blank;0;value<>0)
4. AC6 OR(Blank;0;value<>0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Array Formula in Y6 as follows:

```
=index(Z6:AC6,match(true,1/Z6:AC6>0,0))
```

and press Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Thank you very much Oliver! It works perfectly for my needs. Could you maybe explain to me, what *1/Z6:AC6>0* exactly means and why I have to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, it seems it works also without.

Comment: `1/Z6:AC6>0` requests Excel to calculate the reciprocal of every value with the range and compare the result with 0.  Both 0 or #N/A will return error in this test. The first positive value will return TRUE.  #VALUE! will be returned if you don't press Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Just realized that the formula will fail if values<0.  You can use `=INDEX(Z6:AC6,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1/Z6:AC6),0))` instead.  Similar logic. You can use Formula->Evaluate Formula to see what is happening for each step.